# How to catch Plugin errors in QWebView

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I am using QWebView to load websites which has adobe flash(e.g. youtube videos). so that QWebView interacts with Adobe flash player plugin already installed in my machine, but in case if there is any error occured within plugin , then how to catch it in QWebView? so that at least I can display some error message to my user to take some further action.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a Flash question more than a Qt one. You can use a library like [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed the Flash file. SWFObject will also allow you to display alternative content if Flash is not available, so you can use that to display some message or link to download the Flash plugin.

Comment: No actually QWebView is quite interactive , I used it to fetch the embedded url conatained in the flash with the help of urlchanged signal. for e.g. in a running youtube video when some advertise comes although these ads are there in flash but QWebView works fantastic there and with this signal we can retrieve it.